# Rails 4, ruby-2.0.0-p247, pow, rvm - LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, rack-pow

I've been having a bunch of issues with pow all of a sudden and I cannot figure out why.

I have my app at `/path/to/app` and symlinked it to pow:

`$ cd ~./pow`
`$ ln -s /path/to/app app_name`

I have my app set up with rvm:

`$ rvm -v`
`rvm 1.25.0 (stable)`

and my gemset set up with `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset`. When I check `rvm list` and `rvm gemset list` I do get the right ruby version and gemset specified.

```
$ rvm list
rvm rubies
   ruby-1.9.3-p362 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p353 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

$ rvm gemset list
gemsets for ruby-2.0.0-p247 (found in /Users/anthony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247)
   (default)
=> appgemset
```

Here is the issue: when I visit `app_name.dev/` in browser I get the following error.

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
~/path/to/app/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
~/path/to/app/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
~/path/to/app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
~/path/to/app/config.ru:2:in `block in <main>'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/builder.rb:4:in `instance_eval'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/builder.rb:4:in `initialize'
~/path/to/app/config.ru:1:in `new'
~/path/to/app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:50:in `eval'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:50:in `load_config'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:43:in `initialize'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:13:in `new'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:13:in `run'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/bin/nack_worker:4:in `<main>'
```

Now as per the pow trouble shooting guide, I tried

`echo "export POW_RVM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.powconfig`

while replacing `/usr/local/rvm/` with my rvm installation location and restarted pow. Didn't work.

I've installed bundler in my global gemset, but didn't fix it:

```
$ rvm gemset use global && gem install bundler
```

I also tried uninstalling pow and reinstalling but to no avail. 
I double and triple checked that my app is using the correct version of ruby. 
Additionally, pow works with other apps that I have symlinked.

Anyone have any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you read this first http://rvm.io/integration/pow ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a `.powrc` file in the root of your project and paste the following code:

```
if [ -f "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm" ]; then
  source "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm"
  rvm use .
fi
```

Close the terminal, `cd` to your project and restart the server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually already had the .powrc, forgot to mention that earlier

Comment: does the .powrc contains that script? close the terminal and cd to the project again.